# Function that will test for valid IP Address Syntax and Domain Name Syntax

Tags: c#, parsing, syntax, ip-address, domain-name

I have a TextBox in a Windows Form that allows a user to enter the Host Address of his device. The user is allowed to enter an IP Address or a Domain Name and I would like to validate that the users' syntax is correct (I'm not concerned whether or not the host address is alive - I'm only concerned about the syntax).

Is there a single .NET (2.0) function (i.e. HostAddress.TryParse()) that will test the syntax of a given host address for an IP and a Domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing that will test both and I don't know about built in host address validation either (unless you are happy with `Uri.TryParse` and checking that the segments that should be empty are empty).

You can use `IPAddress.TryParse` in your own validation function.